# ZeroMQ Request/Response pattern with Node.js

Tags: zeromq

I'm implementing a distributed system for a project and am a bit confused as to how I should properly implement the Req/Res pattern. Basically I have a few endpoints that will send a request to a client for processing tasks and responding.

So basically:

1. Incoming request is received
2. The endpoint opens a req and res socket type with the broker
3. Broker receives the request, proxies it to an available worker
4. Worker responds and the endpoint receives the processed value, reports it back via the endpoint.

I've found a decent load balance broker script here: http://zguide.zeromq.org/js:lbbroker. There's also an async client/server pattern I'm interested in implementing: http://zguide.zeromq.org/js:asyncsrv which I might adapt into a load balanced implementation.

My question is perhaps a bit simplistic but, would each endpoint open a new socket on EVERY request or maintain and open socket for every request? That means there would be n connections for every request made to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You'd keep the sockets open, there's no need to close them after each request. And there'd be a single socket one every endpoint (client and server). At the server end you read a request from the socket, and write your response back to the socket; zmq takes care of ensuring that the response goes back from the right client.